# apache fop 2.7 with spring boot 2.7.1 getting failed to generate pdf

Tags: spring-boot, apache-fop

After changed the version of apache fop and spring boot getting below details in console and unable to generate pdf.
anyone can please help me on it got stuck from last couple of days.

```
SystemId Unknown; Line #6; Column #148; "master-name" attribute is not allowed on the fo:simple-page-master element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #6; Column #148; "page-height" attribute is not allowed on the fo:simple-page-master element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #6; Column #148; "page-width" attribute is not allowed on the fo:simple-page-master element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #6; Column #148; "margin-left" attribute is not allowed on the fo:simple-page-master element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #6; Column #148; "margin-right" attribute is not allowed on the fo:simple-page-master element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #6; Column #148; "margin-bottom" attribute is not allowed on the fo:simple-page-master element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #7; Column #46; "margin-top" attribute is not allowed on the fo:region-body element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #10; Column #51; "master-reference" attribute is not allowed on the fo:page-sequence element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #11; Column #46; "flow-name" attribute is not allowed on the fo:flow element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #12; Column #56; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #12; Column #56; "border-width" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #57; "table-layout" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #57; "width" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #14; Column #43; "height" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-body element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #15; Column #108; "border" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-row element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #15; Column #108; "border-left" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-row element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #15; Column #108; "border-right" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-row element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #15; Column #108; "border-top" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-row element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #16; Column #48; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #17; Column #66; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #17; Column #66; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #18; Column #69; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #18; Column #69; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #38; Column #55; "margin-right" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #39; Column #90; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #39; Column #90; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #39; Column #90; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #45; Column #69; "table-layout" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #45; Column #69; "width" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #46; Column #57; "height" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-body element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #48; Column #71; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #49; Column #68; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #51; Column #70; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #52; Column #68; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #58; Column #71; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #59; Column #68; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #61; Column #70; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #62; Column #68; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #68; Column #71; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #69; Column #68; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #71; Column #70; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #72; Column #68; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #95; Column #57; "table-layout" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #95; Column #57; "width" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #96; Column #43; "height" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-body element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #99; Column #48; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #100; Column #84; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #100; Column #84; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #100; Column #84; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #101; Column #66; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #101; Column #66; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #102; Column #52; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #119; Column #48; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #120; Column #68; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #120; Column #68; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #121; Column #52; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #127; Column #48; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #128; Column #68; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #128; Column #68; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #129; Column #52; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #133; Column #69; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #133; Column #69; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #141; Column #48; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #142; Column #68; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #142; Column #68; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #143; Column #52; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:inline element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #147; Column #49; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #148; Column #68; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #148; Column #68; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #150; Column #55; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:inline element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #162; Column #57; "table-layout" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #162; Column #57; "width" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #163; Column #43; "height" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-body element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #165; Column #87; "border" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-row element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #165; Column #87; "background-color" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-row element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #166; Column #48; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #167; Column #66; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #167; Column #66; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #169; Column #82; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #169; Column #82; "border-left" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #170; Column #66; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #170; Column #66; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #175; Column #83; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #175; Column #83; "border-left" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #176; Column #67; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #176; Column #67; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #185; Column #91; "border" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-row element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #185; Column #91; "background-color" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-row element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #186; Column #42; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #187; Column #61; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #187; Column #61; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #189; Column #42; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #190; Column #61; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #190; Column #61; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #194; Column #43; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #194; Column #89; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #194; Column #89; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #206; Column #49; "table-layout" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #206; Column #49; "width" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #207; Column #34; "height" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-body element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #209; Column #37; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #210; Column #54; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #210; Column #54; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #211; Column #67; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:inline element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #223; Column #65; "table-layout" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #223; Column #65; "width" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #224; Column #53; "height" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-body element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #226; Column #62; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #227; Column #82; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #227; Column #82; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #228; Column #71; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:inline element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #234; Column #62; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #235; Column #82; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #235; Column #82; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #236; Column #71; "font-weight" attribute is not allowed on the fo:inline element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #256; Column #105; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #256; Column #105; "border-left" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #256; Column #105; "border-right" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #257; Column #52; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #257; Column #52; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #261; Column #105; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #261; Column #105; "border-left" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #261; Column #105; "border-right" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #262; Column #53; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #262; Column #53; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #267; Column #107; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #267; Column #107; "border-left" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #267; Column #107; "border-right" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #268; Column #54; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #268; Column #54; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #276; Column #76; "border" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-row element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #276; Column #76; "background-color" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-row element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #277; Column #38; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #278; Column #57; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #278; Column #57; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #280; Column #38; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #281; Column #57; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #281; Column #57; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #286; Column #42; "padding" attribute is not allowed on the fo:table-cell element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #287; Column #58; "text-align" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #287; Column #58; "font-size" attribute is not allowed on the fo:block element!



(Location of error unknown)org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Element "fo:simple-page-master" is missing required property "master-name"! (No context info available)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpgxu.png)

Comment: Hi
got the solution from below links.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030909/setting-secure-processing-in-transformerfactory-leads-to-problems-in-xsl

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2591

Comment: Yes that's the answer